# Unable to install build-essential package on Kubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: apt, software-installation, gcc

After running `sudo apt-get install build-essential`

I got

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  dpkg-dev fakeroot g++ g++-11 gcc gcc-11 libalgorithm-diff-perl libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libalgorithm-merge-perl
  libasan6 libfakeroot libgcc-11-dev libstdc++-11-dev lto-disabled-list
Suggested packages:
  debian-keyring g++-multilib g++-11-multilib gcc-11-doc gcc-multilib autoconf automake libtool flex bison gcc-doc
  gcc-11-multilib gcc-11-locales libstdc++-11-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  build-essential dpkg-dev fakeroot g++ g++-11 gcc gcc-11 libalgorithm-diff-perl libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl
  libalgorithm-merge-perl libasan6 libfakeroot libgcc-11-dev libstdc++-11-dev lto-disabled-list
0 upgraded, 15 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 2,283 kB/39.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 128 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libasan6 amd64 11.2.0-19ubuntu1 [2,283 kB]
Err:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libasan6 amd64 11.2.0-19ubuntu1
  Hash Sum mismatch
  Hashes of expected file:
   - SHA512:879b51c208b36729446f0652016d4b3731a7e742a67ce84240122cd88714cb4b548950edb6f0723e296dd7f0621a6dd84823c6087b87bc1519c17e09cbb07656
   - SHA256:94d9f1889bdec4aef6a37f8afd84346e1bcdaa65c158f5647b09781c1f4401e4
   - SHA1:7a40b9444a06b644a72485a4cfedd828dd43ad19 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:d88dd5768dcbf199a2dacfbbbbccb405 [weak]
   - Filesize:2283282 [weak]
  Hashes of received file:
   - SHA512:4625ca49a97b8e1491835c2be9ddaf6349bc7f994eb653ec7007bb2e8e198e11cb8f81775ecb005bf8b5596319f37504103d908e7497a123b4518a2e6f9cbfe5
   - SHA256:f9e9c4713e0596f4cff736d61591a91dfb75427749ab2d4b33790eba7545e591
   - SHA1:966a7d0cedf809a5fba8009b770e442ed6191d9f [weak]
   - MD5Sum:30f1f833b5c6543d09d5325d8b0dffa4 [weak]
   - Filesize:2283282 [weak]
  Last modification reported: Thu, 24 Mar 2022 17:54:28 +0000
Fetched 2,283 kB in 1s (3,666 kB/s)   
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-11/libasan6_11.2.0-19ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
   Hashes of expected file:
    - SHA512:879b51c208b36729446f0652016d4b3731a7e742a67ce84240122cd88714cb4b548950edb6f0723e296dd7f0621a6dd84823c6087b87bc1519c17e09cbb07656
    - SHA256:94d9f1889bdec4aef6a37f8afd84346e1bcdaa65c158f5647b09781c1f4401e4
    - SHA1:7a40b9444a06b644a72485a4cfedd828dd43ad19 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:d88dd5768dcbf199a2dacfbbbbccb405 [weak]
    - Filesize:2283282 [weak]
   Hashes of received file:
    - SHA512:4625ca49a97b8e1491835c2be9ddaf6349bc7f994eb653ec7007bb2e8e198e11cb8f81775ecb005bf8b5596319f37504103d908e7497a123b4518a2e6f9cbfe5
    - SHA256:f9e9c4713e0596f4cff736d61591a91dfb75427749ab2d4b33790eba7545e591
    - SHA1:966a7d0cedf809a5fba8009b770e442ed6191d9f [weak]
    - MD5Sum:30f1f833b5c6543d09d5325d8b0dffa4 [weak]
    - Filesize:2283282 [weak]
   Last modification reported: Thu, 24 Mar 2022 17:54:28 +0000
```

**Then as suggested** I ran `sudo apt-get install build-essential --fix-missing` which gave this error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  dpkg-dev fakeroot g++ g++-11 gcc gcc-11 libalgorithm-diff-perl libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libalgorithm-merge-perl
  libasan6 libfakeroot libgcc-11-dev libstdc++-11-dev lto-disabled-list
Suggested packages:
  debian-keyring g++-multilib g++-11-multilib gcc-11-doc gcc-multilib autoconf automake libtool flex bison gcc-doc
  gcc-11-multilib gcc-11-locales libstdc++-11-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  build-essential dpkg-dev fakeroot g++ g++-11 gcc gcc-11 libalgorithm-diff-perl libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl
  libalgorithm-merge-perl libasan6 libfakeroot libgcc-11-dev libstdc++-11-dev lto-disabled-list
0 upgraded, 15 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 2,283 kB/39.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 128 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libasan6 amd64 11.2.0-19ubuntu1 [2,283 kB]
Err:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libasan6 amd64 11.2.0-19ubuntu1
  Hash Sum mismatch
  Hashes of expected file:
   - SHA512:879b51c208b36729446f0652016d4b3731a7e742a67ce84240122cd88714cb4b548950edb6f0723e296dd7f0621a6dd84823c6087b87bc1519c17e09cbb07656
   - SHA256:94d9f1889bdec4aef6a37f8afd84346e1bcdaa65c158f5647b09781c1f4401e4
   - SHA1:7a40b9444a06b644a72485a4cfedd828dd43ad19 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:d88dd5768dcbf199a2dacfbbbbccb405 [weak]
   - Filesize:2283282 [weak]
  Hashes of received file:
   - SHA512:4625ca49a97b8e1491835c2be9ddaf6349bc7f994eb653ec7007bb2e8e198e11cb8f81775ecb005bf8b5596319f37504103d908e7497a123b4518a2e6f9cbfe5
   - SHA256:f9e9c4713e0596f4cff736d61591a91dfb75427749ab2d4b33790eba7545e591
   - SHA1:966a7d0cedf809a5fba8009b770e442ed6191d9f [weak]
   - MD5Sum:30f1f833b5c6543d09d5325d8b0dffa4 [weak]
   - Filesize:2283282 [weak]
  Last modification reported: Thu, 24 Mar 2022 17:54:28 +0000
Fetched 2,283 kB in 1s (4,052 kB/s)   
Selecting previously unselected package libgcc-11-dev:amd64.
(Reading database ... 217900 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../00-libgcc-11-dev_11.2.0-19ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgcc-11-dev:amd64 (11.2.0-19ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package gcc-11.
Preparing to unpack .../01-gcc-11_11.2.0-19ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gcc-11 (11.2.0-19ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package gcc.
Preparing to unpack .../02-gcc_4%3a11.2.0-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gcc (4:11.2.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libstdc++-11-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../03-libstdc++-11-dev_11.2.0-19ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libstdc++-11-dev:amd64 (11.2.0-19ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package g++-11.
Preparing to unpack .../04-g++-11_11.2.0-19ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking g++-11 (11.2.0-19ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package g++.
Preparing to unpack .../05-g++_4%3a11.2.0-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking g++ (4:11.2.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package lto-disabled-list.
Preparing to unpack .../06-lto-disabled-list_24_all.deb ...
Unpacking lto-disabled-list (24) ...
Selecting previously unselected package dpkg-dev.
Preparing to unpack .../07-dpkg-dev_1.21.1ubuntu2_all.deb ...
Unpacking dpkg-dev (1.21.1ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package build-essential.
Preparing to unpack .../08-build-essential_12.9ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking build-essential (12.9ubuntu3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libfakeroot:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../09-libfakeroot_1.28-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libfakeroot:amd64 (1.28-1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package fakeroot.
Preparing to unpack .../10-fakeroot_1.28-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking fakeroot (1.28-1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libalgorithm-diff-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../11-libalgorithm-diff-perl_1.201-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libalgorithm-diff-perl (1.201-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../12-libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl_0.04-6build3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl (0.04-6build3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libalgorithm-merge-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../13-libalgorithm-merge-perl_0.08-3_all.deb ...
Unpacking libalgorithm-merge-perl (0.08-3) ...
Setting up lto-disabled-list (24) ...
Setting up libalgorithm-diff-perl (1.201-1) ...
Setting up libfakeroot:amd64 (1.28-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up dpkg-dev (1.21.1ubuntu2) ...
Setting up fakeroot (1.28-1ubuntu1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/fakeroot-sysv to provide /usr/bin/fakeroot (fakeroot) in auto mode
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgcc-11-dev:amd64:
 libgcc-11-dev:amd64 depends on libasan6 (>= 11.2.0-19ubuntu1); however:
  Package libasan6:amd64 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libgcc-11-dev:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gcc-11:
 gcc-11 depends on libgcc-11-dev (= 11.2.0-19ubuntu1); however:
  Package libgcc-11-dev:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gcc-11 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                        Setting up libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl (0.04-6build3) ...
Setting up libalgorithm-merge-perl (0.08-3) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of g++-11:
 g++-11 depends on gcc-11 (= 11.2.0-19ubuntu1); however:
  Package gcc-11 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package g++-11 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                            dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gcc:
 gcc depends on gcc-11 (>= 11.2.0-1~); however:
  Package gcc-11 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gcc (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libstdc++-11-dev:amd64:
 libstdc++-11-dev:amd64 depends on libgcc-11-dev (= 11.2.0-19ubuntu1); however:
  Package libgcc-11-dev:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libstdc++-11-dev:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of g++:
 g++ depends on gcc (= 4:11.2.0-1ubuntu1); however:
  Package gcc is not configured yet.
 g++ depends on g++-11 (>= 11.2.0-1~); however:
  Package g++-11 is not configured yet.
 g++ depends on gcc-11 (>= 11.2.0-1~); however:
  Package gcc-11 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package g++ (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of build-essential:
 build-essential depends on gcc (>= 4:10.2); however:
  Package gcc is not configured yet.
 build-essential depends on g++ (>= 4:10.2); however:
  Package g++ is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package build-essential (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libgcc-11-dev:amd64
 gcc-11
 g++-11
 gcc
 libstdc++-11-dev:amd64
 g++
 build-essential
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-11/libasan6_11.2.0-19ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
   Hashes of expected file:
    - SHA512:879b51c208b36729446f0652016d4b3731a7e742a67ce84240122cd88714cb4b548950edb6f0723e296dd7f0621a6dd84823c6087b87bc1519c17e09cbb07656
    - SHA256:94d9f1889bdec4aef6a37f8afd84346e1bcdaa65c158f5647b09781c1f4401e4
    - SHA1:7a40b9444a06b644a72485a4cfedd828dd43ad19 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:d88dd5768dcbf199a2dacfbbbbccb405 [weak]
    - Filesize:2283282 [weak]
   Hashes of received file:
    - SHA512:4625ca49a97b8e1491835c2be9ddaf6349bc7f994eb653ec7007bb2e8e198e11cb8f81775ecb005bf8b5596319f37504103d908e7497a123b4518a2e6f9cbfe5
    - SHA256:f9e9c4713e0596f4cff736d61591a91dfb75427749ab2d4b33790eba7545e591
    - SHA1:966a7d0cedf809a5fba8009b770e442ed6191d9f [weak]
    - MD5Sum:30f1f833b5c6543d09d5325d8b0dffa4 [weak]
    - Filesize:2283282 [weak]
   Last modification reported: Thu, 24 Mar 2022 17:54:28 +0000
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

<br><br>

**Also tried to fix broken packages** `sudo apt --fix-broken install` <br><br>

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libasan6
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libasan6
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
7 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 2,283 kB of archives.
After this operation, 7,697 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libasan6 amd64 11.2.0-19ubuntu1 [2,283 kB]
Err:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libasan6 amd64 11.2.0-19ubuntu1
  Hash Sum mismatch
  Hashes of expected file:
   - SHA512:879b51c208b36729446f0652016d4b3731a7e742a67ce84240122cd88714cb4b548950edb6f0723e296dd7f0621a6dd84823c6087b87bc1519c17e09cbb07656
   - SHA256:94d9f1889bdec4aef6a37f8afd84346e1bcdaa65c158f5647b09781c1f4401e4
   - SHA1:7a40b9444a06b644a72485a4cfedd828dd43ad19 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:d88dd5768dcbf199a2dacfbbbbccb405 [weak]
   - Filesize:2283282 [weak]
  Hashes of received file:
   - SHA512:4625ca49a97b8e1491835c2be9ddaf6349bc7f994eb653ec7007bb2e8e198e11cb8f81775ecb005bf8b5596319f37504103d908e7497a123b4518a2e6f9cbfe5
   - SHA256:f9e9c4713e0596f4cff736d61591a91dfb75427749ab2d4b33790eba7545e591
   - SHA1:966a7d0cedf809a5fba8009b770e442ed6191d9f [weak]
   - MD5Sum:30f1f833b5c6543d09d5325d8b0dffa4 [weak]
   - Filesize:2283282 [weak]
  Last modification reported: Thu, 24 Mar 2022 17:54:28 +0000
Fetched 2,283 kB in 1s (4,472 kB/s)
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-11/libasan6_11.2.0-19ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
   Hashes of expected file:
    - SHA512:879b51c208b36729446f0652016d4b3731a7e742a67ce84240122cd88714cb4b548950edb6f0723e296dd7f0621a6dd84823c6087b87bc1519c17e09cbb07656
    - SHA256:94d9f1889bdec4aef6a37f8afd84346e1bcdaa65c158f5647b09781c1f4401e4
    - SHA1:7a40b9444a06b644a72485a4cfedd828dd43ad19 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:d88dd5768dcbf199a2dacfbbbbccb405 [weak]
    - Filesize:2283282 [weak]
   Hashes of received file:
    - SHA512:4625ca49a97b8e1491835c2be9ddaf6349bc7f994eb653ec7007bb2e8e198e11cb8f81775ecb005bf8b5596319f37504103d908e7497a123b4518a2e6f9cbfe5
    - SHA256:f9e9c4713e0596f4cff736d61591a91dfb75427749ab2d4b33790eba7545e591
    - SHA1:966a7d0cedf809a5fba8009b770e442ed6191d9f [weak]
    - MD5Sum:30f1f833b5c6543d09d5325d8b0dffa4 [weak]
    - Filesize:2283282 [weak]
   Last modification reported: Thu, 24 Mar 2022 17:54:28 +0000
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

But, nah nothing working need assistance to run g++ on my Kubuntu. There seems to be some issue with a single package `libasan6`. (Also can't update it from discover)

Comment: Run `sudo apt clean` and try again.

Comment: Also try switching to the main server instead of the server specific to India. https://askubuntu.com/a/192388/124466

Comment: Thanks @ArchismanPanigrahi, changing server to main did work